# jquery form wizard for dynamic form pages available?

Tags: jquery

I'm building a form wizard with back and forward buttons and which includes some dynamic forms - where the user can add or remove some (product) fields by means of javascript. In order to avoid re-inventing the wheel I was looking for some available jquery form wizards that support such dynamic pages. There's a quite a number of jquery wizard solutions there, but based on some study I got the strong impression they are only meant for static forms (?).

Does anybody know a suitable jquery solution wizard that support dynamic form pages (so that that if the user goes back to the previous formpage with fields added dynamically by javascript, the filled in info on that page is not lost.

Please your help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wicket-Jquery](http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/wizard/DefaultWizardPage?1)UI plugin provides the requested feature of having the dynamic form with form data coming from WEB SERVER and then navigating through the form back and forth with data persistence feature.